# Using GitHub with Multiple Accounts on the 1 Machine

Tags: git, github

I am having trouble getting multiple GitHub accounts working on the 1 machine (Windows 11).
Here's the scenario.
My work has a Github account. Let's call it jonatwork.
I have a personal Github account. Let's call it jonathome.

I already set up ssh for jonathome, with `id_rsa` as my ssh key.

These are the steps I took to create a second ssh key etc. for jonatwork.

-1- I created a new ssh key called id_rsa_jonwork
-2- I added that key to the ssh keys on that GitHub account (jonatwork), using the GitHub site. (Basically copied the public key, dumped it in a textbox, named it and clicked add key).
-3- I created a file in ~/.ssh called config, the contents of which are:

```
#jonwork account
Host jonwork
    HostName github.com
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_jonwork

#jonhome account
Host jonhome
    HostName github.com
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

With that in place, I created a new repo on the jonatwork GitHub account using the GitHub site. I then cloned that repo, with `jonwork:` as a suffix.

I added the name and email to that repo using bash.

When I went to do my first `push`, I was prompted for the password for the jonatwork ssh key. This boded well.

But when I looked at the Github interface, the User for that commit was listed as jonathome.

This is the wrong user. So, that repo had 2 users contributing. jonatwork did the first commit (on creation in the interface) and jonathome (wrong user) did the 2nd commit (pushed via bash).

Can anyone see what I have missed to achieve this?

Comment: It's likely that you also need to make sure the repo's git user is set to the correct one. `git config --local user.email ...`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have done that. Verified in the config file in the .git directory.

Comment: @onefootswill what is the complete remote for the origins? Find out with `git remote --verbose`. I have remotes called `git@gtihub.com:user/repo.git` and in other gits I have `git@work-github.com:userwork/repo2.git` where I have the hosts `github.com` and `work-github.com` setup much like you have. This way ssh config will deduce the proper credentials as connected with a domain alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I looked at the Github interface, the User for that commit was listed as jonathome.

This has nothing to do with SSH authentication.

You can check the user locally, before any push, with `git log --pretty=" %C(reset)%ad %C(Cyan)%an: %C(reset)%s"`, to see the author used for your commits.

```
git log --pretty=" %C(reset)%ad %C(Cyan)%an: %C(reset)%s"
```

It is that author which would be displayed on GitHub once pushed.

---

As the [OP onefootswill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540156/onefootswill) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72054146/using-github-with-multiple-accounts-on-the-1-machine/72054483#comment127347798_72054483):

> Problem was between the chair and the keyboard.
> I had not restarted the bash shell after setting the local user of the repo. So, was continuing to use the global user.

Comment: Be that as it may, why did it use the wrong user when I committed code locally?

Comment: @onefootswill That is entirely done to your Git config. Check the output of `git config --show-origin --show-scope -l|grep user`, done form your local repository folder.

Comment: Indeed. The local user is correct (the work user). The global user is the home user. That's the bit I don't get. I actually set those values for this repo, locally.

Comment: @onefootswill OK. Does the git log command in the answer shows the right user?

Comment: It shows that the work user performed the commit. So, it must have been the work user. Big apologies, but I have to pick my wife up now. Will be back online later. Very much appreciate you help.

Comment: I figured this out. Problem was between the chair and the keyboard. I had not restarted the bash shell after setting the local user of the repo. So, was continuing to use the global user. Cheers.